# Using Weave net in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mesos, marathon, weave

I had a docker image that has Hadoop,Mesos,Marathon and Zookeeper.I distributed this image among three physical nodes. To run that image, I wrote a docker compose with three services of Zookeeper,Mesos,Marathon. I used **WEAVE_CIDR** for weave IP in the compose file. I defined the same IP weave for three services. When I ran the compose file, Zookeeper ran fine,but I received error for running Mesos because of repetitive IP weave. So, I tried to merge three services in one service to use just one IP weave for three of them. My new docker compose is in following:

```
 version: '3.7'
 services:
  zookeeper:
    image: hadoop_marathon_mesos_flink_2
    command: bash -c "echo zookeeper;
    /home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/zkServer.sh restart;echo mesos;
    sleep 30;/home/mesos-1.7.2/build/bin/mesos-master.sh;
    echo marathon;/home/marathon-1.7.189-48bfd6000/bin/marathon"
    privileged: true
    network_mode: "bridge"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 10
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 5
      WEAVE_CIDR: 10.32.0.1/12
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: 10.32.0.1:2888:3888
      MESOS_CLUSTER: MMM
      LIBPROCESS_IP: 10.32.0.1
      MESOS_QUORUM: 1
      MESOS_LOG_DIR: /var/log/mesos
      MESOS_WORK_DIR: /var/run/mesos
      MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT: 5mins
      HOSTNAME: 10.32.0.1
      MARATHON_ZK: zk://10.32.0.1:2181/marathon
      MARATHON_MASTER: zk://10.32.0.1:2181/mesos
      MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY: /usr/local/lib/libmesos.so
      MARATHON_HTTP_PORT: 8080
      Mesos_HTTP_PORT: 5050
    expose:
     - 2181
     - 2888
     - 3888
     - 5050
     - 4040
     - 7077
     - 8080
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
     - 2888:2888
     - 3888:3888
     - 5050:5050
     - 4040:4040
     - 7077:7077
     - 8080:8080

 networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: weave
```

When I run **docker-compose up**, Zookeeper and Mesos run without error; but Marathon is not run. I want Marathon run just after Mesos,but it does not. Please any one tells me What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I used this docker compose file in Master node. Be careful before running docker compose run **weave expose** in three node to open Marathon and Mesos UI.

```
 version: '3.7'
 services:
  zookeeper:
   image: hadoop_marathon_mesos_flink_2
   command: >
          sh -c "echo zookeeper && 
          /home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/zkServer.sh restart && 
          sleep 30 && /home/mesos-1.7.2/build/bin/mesos-master.sh 
          --ip=10.32.0.1 --hostname=10.32.0.1 --roles=marathon,flink |
         /home/marathon-1.7.189-48bfd6000/bin/marathon --master 10.32.0.1:5050 
         --zk zk://10.32.0.1:2181/marathon --hostname 10.32.0.1 
         --webui_url 10.32.0.1:8080 --logging_level debug"
   privileged: true
   network_mode: "bridge"
   environment:
     WEAVE_CIDR: 10.32.0.1/12
     ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
     ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
     ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
     ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 10
     ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 5
     ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: 10.32.0.1:2888:3888
     MESOS_CLUSTER: MMM
     LIBPROCESS_IP: 10.32.0.1
     MESOS_QUORUM: 1
     MESOS_LOG_DIR: /var/log/mesos
     MESOS_WORK_DIR: /var/run/mesos
     MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT: 5mins
     HOSTNAME: 10.32.0.1
     MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY: /usr/local/lib/libmesos.so
     MESOS_DOCKER_SOCKET: /var/run/weave/weave.sock
   expose:
    - 2181
    - 2888
    - 3888
    - 5050
    - 4040
    - 7077
    - 8080
   ports:
    - 2181:2181
    - 2888:2888
    - 3888:3888
    - 5050:5050
    - 4040:4040
    - 7077:7077
    - 8080:8080

networks:
 default:
  external:
    name: weave
```

Also, I ran this docker compose in slave nodes:

```
 version: '3.7'
 services:
   slave:
    image: hadoop_marathon_mesos_flink_2
    command: sh -c "rm -f /var/run/mesos/meta/slaves/latest &&
           /home/mesos-1.7.2/build/bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=10.32.0.1:5050 
         --port=5051 --work_dir=/var/run/mesos  --systemd_enable_support=fa$
         privileged: true
   network_mode: "bridge"
   environment:
     WEAVE_CIDR: 10.32.0.2/12
     MESOS_RESOURCES: ports(*):[11000-11999]
     LIBPROCESS_IP: 10.32.0.2
     MESOS_HOSTNAME: 10.32.0.2
     MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT: 5mins #also in Dockerfile
     MESOS_LOG_DIR: /var/log/mesos
     MESOS_WORK_DIR: /var/run/mesos
     MESOS_LOGGING_LEVEL: INFO
     MESOS_DOCKER_SOCKET: /var/run/weave/weave.sock
   expose:
    - 5051
   ports:
    - 5051:5051

 networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: weave
```

Hope it was useful.